# Change PHP language $_SESSION variable with AJAX and no page reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a multilingual site (es and en), and I need to change the language of the whole site when the user clicks on any of the language buttons. I store the session variable in `config.php` and load the page in the selected language with the `require` statement:

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_POST['lang']) && (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))) {
        $_POST['lang'] = 'en';
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'];        
    }  else if (isset($_POST['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_POST['lang'] && !empty($_POST['lang'])) {
        if($_POST['lang'] == 'en') 
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
        else if ($_POST['lang'] == 'es') 
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'es';
    }

    require "lang/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
    echo $_SESSION['lang'];
?>
```

`en.php`

```php
<?php 
    $lang = array(
        'mainTitle' => 'What is our business?',
        'mainDescription' => 'Our description'
    );
?>
```

I then make an AJAX call in `main.js` to change the session variable when any of the language buttons are clicked

```js
function loadDoc(str) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // this is to prevent cached results
        url: 'php/config.php?t=' + Math.random(),
        data: {
            lang: str
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('Session language: ' + result)
        },
    }) 
}

$('.langContainer .es').click(() => {
    loadDoc('es')
})

$('.langContainer .en').click(() => {
    loadDoc('en')
})
```

While the AJAX success function returns the changed session variable, the call doesn't change the language of the site until I reload it, which is kind of frustrating.

This could work perfectly with reload by sending a GET request from any of the buttons with anchor tags, but I want to know if it is possible to update the session variable with AJAX so that the content changes in the appropriate language without refreshing the page.

Comment: Given that you are trying to replace the entire page with a different language, you want to reload.  The main point of ajax is to avoid a reload.  It doesn't fit your use case.

Comment: A working (but not good) solution would be to trigger a reload manually via JavaScript in the `success` function. In this case you wouldn't need AJAX at all because @Taplar is right - you could directly reload the page via PHP when one of the language buttons was clicked after changing the language in the session.